# What's wrong with this simple Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window['TestPlugin'] = function(){
    var helloWorld = function(){
        alert('hello world');
    }
}
```

I try calling this as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    TestPlugin.hellowWorld();
}
```

but I get:

> TestPlugin.hellowWorld is not a function

Comment: hellowWorld is not helloWorld...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`helloWorld` is:

- Not defined until you call the `TestPlugin` function
- A local variable inside the function and not a property of the function object

For it to be a property you would need to define it like:

```
window['TestPlugin'] = function(){};
window.TestPlugin.helloWorld = function(){
    alert('hello world');
}
```

But since `TestPlugin` doesn't do anything, it doesn't make much sense for it to be a function, so you might as well just:

```
window['TestPlugin'] = {
    helloWorld: function(){
        alert('hello world');
    }
};
```

You also need to spell it correctly when you call it.

Comment: I guess I over simplified the example too much. SocialPlugin will also have a couple of variables - var name; var userId;

Answer (score 0):

Other than the [assumed] typo - the answer is: *scope*.

helloWorld is *private* to TestPlugin and so not visible outside that scope.

*One* possible way to make this available would be:

```js
window['TestPlugin'] = function(){
    this.helloWorld = function(){
        alert('hello world');
    }
    return this;
}

TestPlugin().helloWorld()
```